# Unable to set preserve order as true in TestNG xml file

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am trying to execute testcases using testng.xml. But for some reason the classes present inside testng.xml are not executing sequentially.It is executing alphabetically. I have given preserve-order as true. But it is showing below mentioned issue while setting it as true.

> redundant default attribute value assignment

I am using intellij as ide.

[image]

Comment: try putting **preserve-order="true"** in suite tag in testng.xml

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to add parameter 'priority' to @Test in your code. Lower priority is executed before higher one.

Comment: I do not want to use priority. If i am able to execute the classes in given order by using preserve-order, then i am fine with it.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the value is set to `True` only. So that's why that warning is shown when you are again setting it to true.